# Animation when mouseover with multiple pictures files

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to animate 3 png files with jquery when the mouse is over the picture
I found this example with text.
I try to modify the html:

```
<div class="img3"><img src=cat1.png></div>
<div class="img3"><img src=cat2.png></div>
<div class="img3"><img src=cat3.png></div>
```

But that doesn't work.

---

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hover_me').hover(function () {
        $('.img5').fadeOut(5000, function () {
            $('.img4').fadeOut(5000, function () {
                $('.img3').fadeOut(5000);
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

<body>
    <div class="hover_me">Hover me</div>
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="img3">3</div>
        <div class="img4">4</div>
        <div class="img5">5</div>
    </div><!--/container-->
</body>
```

---

CSS:

```
.hover_me {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.container div {
    position: absolute;
}

.img3 {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #E5A932;
}

.img4 {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #DC25ED;
}

.img5 {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #15EFD6;
}
```

Comment: "but that doesn t work" It works as expected, so what do you expect?

Comment: Hi,i am trying to do that:
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hover_me').hover(function(){
  $('.img5').fadeOut(5000,function(){
  $('.img4').fadeOut(5000,function(){
  $('.img3').fadeOut(5000);
  });
  });
  });



});
</script>



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    
<body>
    <div class="hover_me">Hover me</div>
<div class="container">   
 
<div class="img3"><img src=cat1.png></div>
<div class="img3"><img src=cat2.png></div>
<div class="img3"><img src=cat3.png></div>
    </div><!--/container-->
</body>

Comment: i have some problem posting... sorry

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

I have no idea why you couldnt get it work. The code above itself works perfectly.
May be you are not including the jquery properly.
you must include jquery like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

if you are not having that file in your root.

fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/hpZwZ/1/